# unexpected else (T_ELSE)

Tags: php, html, forms, syntax-error

This is the current code I have:

It wasn't self destructing when

```
if(!$_SESSION['answer']){$_SESSION['answer'] = rand(0,$_POST['amount']);}
```

was

```
if(!$_SESSION['answer']){$_SESSION['answer'] = rand(0,$_POST['amount']);
```

I don't exactly know what I am doing nor do I understand programming jargon, I'm fairly new to all of this and would appreciate it if you can figure out this syntax error that is most likely really simple but i just can't see it.

Edit: note I do not want you to correct any other code but the syntax error TY!

```
<? session_start(); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title> Jelly bean Game </title>
</head>
<body>
<?php

  if(!$_POST["submit"]){
    SESSION_DESTROY();
?>


<h2> Jelly Bean game! <h2>

<form action="<?=$_SERVER['php_self']?>" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="amount" placeholder="Add your jellybeans"/>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="add">
</form>

<?
}else{
$amount = $_POST['amount']; //variable
$guess = $_POST['guess']; //variable
$gz = ""; // empty variable

if(!$_SESSION['amount']){$_SESSION['amount'] =$amount;}
if(!$_SESSION['answer']){$_SESSION['answer'] = rand(0,$_POST['amount']);}
if(!ctype_digit($amount)){$error[] = "please do not use letters dots or     symbols when submitting the amount of beans you want to use!";}
if($error){
  echo "<div class=\"errorbox\">";
foreach($error as $val){
  submitAgainForm();
  echo "<p>" . $val . "</p>";
}
echo "</div>";


    }elseif($_POST['guess'] == ""){
        echo "Take a guess!";
        echo $amount;
        echo $answer . "123";
        guessAgainForm();
    }else{
      if($_POST['guess'] > $_SESSION['answer']){
      echo "The guess you have enter was too high, please try again!";}
    }else{
      if(!ctype_digit($guess)){
        echo "please do not put dots/letters or symbols in your guess!";
      }
    }else{
      if($_POST['guess'] < $_SESSION['answer']){
        echo "===echo===3==="; // to see if the code is working
        $gz = "The guess you have entered was too high, please try again!";
        echo $gz;
        guessAgainForm();
      }
    }else{
      if($_POST['guess'] == $_SESSION['answer']){
        $gz = "You have guessed the exact number of jelly beans     Congratulations!";
        echo $answer;
        echo $gz;
        playAgainForm();
  }
}}
 ?>




<?
function guessAgainForm(){

?>
<form action="<?=$_SERVER['php_self']?>" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="guess" placeholder="guess!"/>
  <p><button type="submit" name="submit" value="guess"> Guess! </button></p>
</form>
<?
}
?>


<?
function submitAgainForm(){
?>
<form action="<?=$_SERVER['php_self']?>" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="amount" placeholder="Add your jellybeans"/>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="add">
</form>
<?
}
?>

<?
function playAgainForm(){
?>
<br>
 <a href="https://
<REDACTED>> Play Again !    </a>

  <?
}
  ?>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line before asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should [edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: Wow, this code styling is horrible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only have one `else` per if-elsif-else statement. Just change the places where you have an `if` condition insdide an `else` to `elseif`s and you should be OK. E.g.:

```
} elseif ($_POST['guess'] > $_SESSION['answer']) {
    echo "The guess you have enter was too high, please try again!";
}
// etc...
```

Answer (score 0):

Just replace following code. And also use `elseif` condition. You have use every time `else`.

```
 if(!$_POST["submit"]){
    SESSION_DESTROY();
```

To...

```
  if(!$_POST["submit"]){
    SESSION_DESTROY();
  }
```